# Split a dataframe where every row is a list into columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a single column in a pandas dataframe. Every row is made of a list. All the lists have the same length.

```
0
________________________________________________________
0   [86232, 2019-09-12, INTERNET, ... , N ]
1   [86233, 2019-09-12, INTERNET, ... , M ]
2   [86234, 2019-09-12, MEZZO LIBERO, ...  , Q ]
3   ...
```

I want to split every element of every list in a different column. So the final result would look something like this:

```
1     |2           | 3            | ... | 33
______________________________________________
86232 | 2019-09-12 | INTERNET     | ... | N
86233 | 2019-09-12 | INTERNET     | ... | M
86234 | 2019-09-12 | MEZZO LIBERO | ... | Q
```

What's the easiest way to do it with Pandas?

These is the dict schema

```
{0: {0: (86232, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 0, 0), 'INTERNET', 'A.M Web', 'Brand_SMG', 0.0, 'gen', '20_FCST', 'OnLine', 'dipendente S', 'Low Rev.', 'STx', 'A.M', 'INTERNET', 'Brand_X', 'dipendente S', 'STORICI', 'TIER 1', 1.0, 'TIER 1', 'ALIMENTARI', '04_SRM', 'SMX', 'ALTRI', 'STC', 'Reservation', 'Off + On', 'Online_R', 'TIER 1', None, None, None, None),
  1: (86233, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 0, 0), 'INTERNET', 'A.m Web', 'Brand_SMX', 0.0, 'feb', '20_FCST', 'OnLine', 'dipendente S', 'Low Rev.', 'STx', 'A.M', 'INTERNET', 'Brand_SMX', 'dipendente S', 'STORICI', 'TIER 1', 1.0, 'TIER 1', 'ALIMENTARI', '04_SRM', 'SMX', 'ALTRI', 'STC', 'Reservation', 'Off + On', 'Online_R', 'TIER 1', None, None, None, None)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(df[0].tolist())
```

Comment: I have already tried but it doesn't work. It gives me back the same dataframe

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]})

a = []
b = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a.append(row['a'][0])
    b.append(row['a'][1])

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
print(new_df)
```